# limit at infinity of a function of $n$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, combinatorics, ordinary-differential-equations

I'm trying to solve the following limit:$$
\lim _{n \rightarrow \infty} \sum_{k=0}^n \frac{(2 k) !}{4^k(k !)^2(2 k+1)}-\frac{\pi}{2}
$$

I've thought about using the series:$$
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{2^n n !^2}{(2 n+1) !}=1+\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1 \cdot 2}{3 \cdot 5}+\frac{1 \cdot 2 \cdot 3}{3 \cdot 5 \cdot 7}+\cdots=\frac{\pi}{2}
$$

But I still can't see which procedure is the best to continue.

Could someone give me a clue or help to continue with the value of the limit?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Firstly, the generating function for the central binomial coefficients, $G(x)$, is given by
$$G(x) = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(2k)!}{(k!)^2} x^k.$$
Using binomial thoerem, you can verify that
$$G(x) = (1 - 4x)^{-1/2}$$
Hence,
$$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(2k)!}{(k!)^2 (2k+1)} \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{2k} = 2 \int_{0}^{1/2} G(t^2) \ dt$$
(as $t = 1/2$ is inside the interval of convergence of $G(t^2)$)
$$= 2\int_{0}^{1/2} \frac{1}{\sqrt{1 - 4t^2}} \ dt$$
$$= \int_{0}^{1} \frac{1}{\sqrt{1 - t^2}} \ dt$$
$$= \frac{\pi}{2}.$$
So finally the limit tends to $0$ as $n$ tends to infinity.